# Correct use of Promises in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to get my head wrapped around the concept of Promises in AngularJS.

Is the following code on the right track? And could someone explain the `PlateCheckService.checkPlate` method and why if I don't return the promise? `return $http.post().then` why the inner return of the object with the `message` and `alertClass` does not work? I think it is a chained/inner promise?

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
(function () {
"use strict"

var app = angular.module('cs');

app.service('PlateCheckService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
            return $http.post('PlateCheck/Index', {
                plateNumber: plateNumber
            }).then(function (response) {
                return {
                    message: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'Clean' : 'Hot',
                    alertClass: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('PlateCheckCtrl', ['$scope', 'PlateCheckService', function ($scope, PlateCheckService) {
    var plateCheck = {
        plateNumber: '',
        message: '',
        alertClass: '',
        checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
            var _this = this;

            PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber).then(function (response) {
                _this.message = response.message;
                _this.alertClass = response.alertClass;
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.plateCheck = plateCheck;
}]);

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because of chained promises.  Remember that a call to `then` will return a promise before the function it encloses is called.

So, your call here: `PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber)` will expect to return a chained promise.  However, your service's `then` enclosed function is not returning a promise.  Therefore, it will fail to have a `then` function to chain once it is resolved.

You can visualize this with the following psuedo code:

```
$http.get('url')
    .then(function(response) {
        return aPromise;
    })
    .then(function(aPromiseResponse) {
        return bPromise;
    })
    .then(function(bPromiseResponse) {
        return cPromise;
    })
    .then(function(cPromiseResponse) {
        // when scope is available
        $scope.bindToMe = cPromiseResponse.value;
    });
```

If you want to add functionality to a promise chain in a service, then the wrapped promise function needs to return a promise as well.

The easiest way I have found to do this is with `$q.when`. `$q.when` will wrap the object in a promise if the object is not a promise.  If an object is already available (like in your case), then `$q.when` will instantly resolve.  Documentation for `$q.when` is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

So, you should be able to get your code to work by using this in the service:

```
return $q.when({
          message: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'Clean' : 'Hot',
          alertClass: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'
       });
```